# How to post from php with cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, post

How can I make a post request using cookies from php.

My php code:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$id=$_GET[id];

$data = http_build_query( array ('act' => 'load_friends_silent', 'al' => '1', 'gid'=>'0' ,'id'=>$id) );


$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'header'=>"Cookie:     something=asdaefefe",
'method'=>"POST",
'content' => $data
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
print $context;
$contents = file_get_contents('http://vkontakte.ru/al_friends.php', false, $context);

$fil=fopen("./".$id."ne.txt","w");
echo '<br><br>'.$contents;

fputs($fil,$contents);    

fclose($fil);
chmod("./".$id."ne.txt", 0777);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br><br>execute time $time seconds\n";
?>
```

But this code won't work on the server; cookie not sent.

Comment: You question isn't clear, please rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
To use PHP to post to a page that the user will NOT navigate to, you can use CURL:

http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Where in the example, you set $fields to your cookie values:

```
$fields = array(
    'lname' => urlencode($_COOKIE['last_name'] ),
    'fname' => urlencode($_COOKIE['first_name'] ),
    ...
);
```

[EDIT AGAIN]
By your newly posted code it looks like you are trying to create a cookie on the page that you are posting to.  First of all, creating cookies for other websites would seem to be a big security risk, so I'm 99.9% certain that this has never been nor ever will be possible.  Secondly, PHP is not a browser and can't store cookies for other sites...so even if your post created a cookie, the user's browser would not have that cookie.  All you can do is post 'something'=> urlencode('value'), and then the page you are posting to will have to create the cookie on their end.  However, since PHP can't hold cookies since it's not a browser, this would be pointless.

If you want the user's browser to have a cookie, then you need to use something like jQuery's $.post.  Using jQuery's post() method will use the user's browser to go to the page and post data.  The page that gets the posted data can then create a cookie on the user's browser.

[Read These] they may contain some info for you.  Is this what you're trying to do?

[Simulating a cookie-enabled browser in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297952/simulating-a-cookie-enabled-browser-in-php)

[Simulating a POST with PHP & cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925824/simulating-a-post-with-php-curl)

It does sound like CURL should be able to mimic a browser's cookie capabilities...so you might be able to send cookie data, though, as I said, you woudln't be able to set the user to those cookies or anything...since I'm not sure of your purpose, that makes an answer harder:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I want to send cookies with POST.

Comment: Are you using something like jQuery to do a $.post(), or do you want to post a cookie value to the next page after the user interacts with a form?

Comment: PHP can't "POST", a form can post or JavaScript can post...unless you're going to use CURL extensions or something to that effect.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is PHP can't "redirect" a user and POST data with the redirect to my knowledge.  You would have to put the cookie value into the URL string if you want to redirect.  To post to a page that the user will NOT navigate to, you can use CURL.  I linked to an example above in my edit.

Comment: the POST sending parameters & cookies.you say to send cookies as parameter.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking there

Comment: look at my code $data is your $fields , but other than I'm sending cookies

Comment: yes, I've already mentioned...what it looks like you're trying to do...to create cookies on another site with PHP...not really possible to my knowledge, and I don't think it should be.  Read my second edit above.

Comment: look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php  
I copyed code from there and edited

Answer (score 0):

Read this, maybe it will help. http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_cookies.asp